# Changing Parent Class With Child's Button Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parent-child

What i'm basically asking is if i could do this?

```js
function Close(){
  // what the furry mermaids should i put in here!?
  }
```

```css
.vissible {
  display: block;
  }
.hidden {
  display: none;
  }
#parentDiv1{
  background-color: red;
  }
#parentDiv2{
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv1" class="visible">
  <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close()">close</button>
 <p> This is div 1 </p>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv2" class="visible">
 <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close()">close</button>
 <p> This is div 2 </p>
</div>
```

There are two divs that contain the same button but each button changes their parent div's class to hidden. Their parent's div only.
This is because i want to make a lot of pages but they close one by one with the same code and the same button. I'm wanting a minimalist solution here.

Oh and please don't be vague with your answers. If you are going to present it please explain how it works and how to apply it. A working code example is desired.

Note: Only one function may be used and is used by two identical buttons that are separated by two Divs.

Please and Thank You! :D

Comment: You know that you are using the same id twice? Use classes instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `event` in close function and access to parent with `event.target.parentNode`;

```js
function Close(event){
   const parent= event.target.parentNode
   
   parent.classList.remove('vissible');
   parent.classList.add('hidden');
  
  // what the furry mermaids should i put in here!?
  }
```

```css
.vissible {
  display: block;
  }
.hidden {
  display: none;
  }
#parentDiv1{
  background-color: red;
  }
#parentDiv2{
  background-color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv1" class="visible">
  <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close(event)">close</button>
 <p> This is div 1 </p>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv2" class="visible">
 <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close(event)">close</button>
 <p> This is div 2 </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can pass the current element context `this` to method. Then parent div can be accessed using [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode) property. To manipulate element's class use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property.

```
function Close(elem) {
   elem.parentNode.classList.add('hidden')
   elem.parentNode.classList.remove('visible')
}
```

```js
function Close(elem) {
  elem.parentNode.classList.add('hidden')
  elem.parentNode.classList.remove('visible')
}
```

```css
.vissible {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#parentDiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#parentDiv2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv1" class="visible">
  <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close(this)">close</button>
  <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv2" class="visible">
  <button id="closebtn" onclick="Close(this)">close</button>
  <p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
```

I would recommend you to use unobtrusive event handler. Instead of using ugly inline click handler.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.closebtn');
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      this.parentNode.classList.add('hidden');
      this.parentNode.classList.remove('visible');
    })
  });
});
```

```css
.vissible {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#parentDiv1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#parentDiv2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv1" class="visible">
  <button type="button" class="closebtn">close</button>
  <p>This is div 1</p>
</div>
<div id="parentDiv2" class="visible">
  <button type="button" class="closebtn">close</button>
  <p>This is div 2</p>
</div>
```

Comment: lol i did this and i'm afraid it just keeps adding classes and when i ran inspect there were a lot of classes on the divs XD

Comment: @Arkonsol, What exactly is your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :)

https://jsfiddle.net/

```
$('#parentDiv1 #closebtn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden')
})

$('#parentDiv2 #closebtn').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hidden')
})
```

Comment: or what @Gurgy Wurgy did by removing class visible, then adding class hidden would be adviseable.

Comment: what you suggested was kind of not minimalist... and if i happened to create about an estimated 1000 pages.... this would be a nightmare XD coz i'm already using this to navigate while i was figuring things out

Comment: fair enough, I still consider myself quite an amature in jquery, but I like to help people so I try my best ^^ and I've never ever created something with an estimated of 1000 pages. more like 25 +- :P (I'm still in school)

Comment: I recommend you use classes on your buttons though, using the same ID twice on different objects could cause issues.

Comment: Oh no the ID is just for emphasis coz I'm gonna use those for different stuff so I have to give them different IDs to get different results well... Some of them anyway most of em won't have ids only classes

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it. Use something like this.

```
$(".closebtn").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("visible");
    $(this).parent().addClass("hidden");
});
```

Also in your css your class is spelled vissible and in your html the class it spelled visible

Comment: yeah i know :3 The code is just basically a Vague representation of what i was going for so it's pretty much given. That and because i was in a hurry XD

Comment: No worries :) just thought I would mention as I always miss stuff like that